# How to teach emacs on Windows about ~user/ location?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, home-directory

I am running `Emacs v23.3.1` on a Windows 7 machine and would like Emacs to be able to resolve a `~user/` pathname in my start up files to a directory.  It can resolve `~/` fine, I would like `~user/` to resolve likewise.

How can I teach Emacs how to resolve user's home directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the registry entry as it says in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/MS_002dWindows-Registry.html#MS_002dWindows-Registry)

Comment: Which registry entry? I expect 'HOME' is only for `~` not `~username`.